# ASP.NET Gridview in MultiViews

Tags: asp.net, gridview, datasource, multiview

I have a page that users must fill step by step. For this purpose I have multiview this 4 views, and every view contains grid and prev/next buttons. Every grid has different datasource and these datasources are CslaDatasourse. 
The problem is that on previous button click grid's content gets empty. I cannot control it. Here is structure of cs file:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
protected void CslaDataSource1_SelectObject(object sender, Csla.Web.SelectObjectArgs e)
{
   PersonList list = PersonList.GetList();
   e.BusinessObject = list ;
}
protected void PrevBtn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   MultiView1.ActiveViewIndex = 0;
}
```

A serched a lot the solution but could not find working one. Also I'll grateful if you suggest me another way for this type of structured page. 
Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You will gets list empty ,while click on Prev_button .
Please go through page life cycle.

For every event you will load page.

I think ..this sufficient to understand bcos i dun knw your application..I faces same problem , bt i resolved.

Comment: Excuse me, but your is answer is not clear enough and detailed.